libxml2 How to keep tag and property's letter case In Parse
My libxml2 Version is 2.9.10
I tried to parse the HTML and find the SVG from it, and save it in file.
The work went smoothly.
However,I found the saved svg can't not render in browser.
I compared the source svg and saved svg...
source svg:
<svg style="vertical-align: -0.05ex;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4.588ex" height="1.595ex" role="img" focusable="false" viewBox="0 -683 2028 705" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true">
 <defs>
  <path id="MJX-13046891-TEX-N-34" d="M462 0Q444 3 333 3Q217 3 199 0H190V46H221Q241 46 248 46T265 48T279 53T286 61Q287 63 287 115V165H28V211L179 442Q332 674 334 675Q336 677 355 677H373L379 671V211H471V165H379V114Q379 73 379 66T385 54Q393 47 442 46H471V0H462ZM293 211V545L74 212L183 211H293Z"></path>
  <path id="MJX-13046891-TEX-N-2E" d="M78 60Q78 84 95 102T138 120Q162 120 180 104T199 61Q199 36 182 18T139 0T96 17T78 60Z"></path>
  <path id="MJX-13046891-TEX-N-35" d="M164 157Q164 133 148 117T109 101H102Q148 22 224 22Q294 22 326 82Q345 115 345 210Q345 313 318 349Q292 382 260 382H254Q176 382 136 314Q132 307 129 306T114 304Q97 304 95 310Q93 314 93 485V614Q93 664 98 664Q100 666 102 666Q103 666 123 658T178 642T253 634Q324 634 389 662Q397 666 402 666Q410 666 410 648V635Q328 538 205 538Q174 538 149 544L139 546V374Q158 388 169 396T205 412T256 420Q337 420 393 355T449 201Q449 109 385 44T229 -22Q148 -22 99 32T50 154Q50 178 61 192T84 210T107 214Q132 214 148 197T164 157Z"></path>
  <path id="MJX-13046891-TEX-N-56" d="M114 620Q113 621 110 624T107 627T103 630T98 632T91 634T80 635T67 636T48 637H19V683H28Q46 680 152 680Q273 680 294 683H305V637H284Q223 634 223 620Q223 618 313 372T404 126L490 358Q575 588 575 597Q575 616 554 626T508 637H503V683H512Q527 680 627 680Q718 680 724 683H730V637H723Q648 637 627 596Q627 595 515 291T401 -14Q396 -22 382 -22H374H367Q353 -22 348 -14Q346 -12 231 303Q114 617 114 620Z"></path>
 </defs>
 <g stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" transform="scale(1,-1)">
  <g >
   <g >
    <use  xlink:href="#MJX-13046891-TEX-N-34"></use>
    <use  xlink:href="#MJX-13046891-TEX-N-2E" transform="translate(500,0)"></use>
    <use  xlink:href="#MJX-13046891-TEX-N-35" transform="translate(778,0)"></use>
   </g>
   <g  transform="translate(1278,0)">
    <use  xlink:href="#MJX-13046891-TEX-N-56"></use>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>

saved svg:
<svg style="vertical-align: -0.05ex;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4.588ex" height="1.595ex" role="img" focusable="false" viewbox="0 -683 2028 705" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true">
  <defs>
    <path id="MJX-13046891-TEX-N-34" d="M462 0Q444 3 333 3Q217 3 199 0H190V46H221Q241 46 248 46T265 48T279 53T286 61Q287 63 287 115V165H28V211L179 442Q332 674 334 675Q336 677 355 677H373L379 671V211H471V165H379V114Q379 73 379 66T385 54Q393 47 442 46H471V0H462ZM293 211V545L74 212L183 211H293Z"/>
    <path id="MJX-13046891-TEX-N-2E" d="M78 60Q78 84 95 102T138 120Q162 120 180 104T199 61Q199 36 182 18T139 0T96 17T78 60Z"/>
    <path id="MJX-13046891-TEX-N-35" d="M164 157Q164 133 148 117T109 101H102Q148 22 224 22Q294 22 326 82Q345 115 345 210Q345 313 318 349Q292 382 260 382H254Q176 382 136 314Q132 307 129 306T114 304Q97 304 95 310Q93 314 93 485V614Q93 664 98 664Q100 666 102 666Q103 666 123 658T178 642T253 634Q324 634 389 662Q397 666 402 666Q410 666 410 648V635Q328 538 205 538Q174 538 149 544L139 546V374Q158 388 169 396T205 412T256 420Q337 420 393 355T449 201Q449 109 385 44T229 -22Q148 -22 99 32T50 154Q50 178 61 192T84 210T107 214Q132 214 148 197T164 157Z"/>
    <path id="MJX-13046891-TEX-N-56" d="M114 620Q113 621 110 624T107 627T103 630T98 632T91 634T80 635T67 636T48 637H19V683H28Q46 680 152 680Q273 680 294 683H305V637H284Q223 634 223 620Q223 618 313 372T404 126L490 358Q575 588 575 597Q575 616 554 626T508 637H503V683H512Q527 680 627 680Q718 680 724 683H730V637H723Q648 637 627 596Q627 595 515 291T401 -14Q396 -22 382 -22H374H367Q353 -22 348 -14Q346 -12 231 303Q114 617 114 620Z"/>
  </defs>
  <g stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" transform="scale(1,-1)">
    <g>
      <g>
        <use xlink:href="#MJX-13046891-TEX-N-34"/>
        <use xlink:href="#MJX-13046891-TEX-N-2E" transform="translate(500,0)"/>
        <use xlink:href="#MJX-13046891-TEX-N-35" transform="translate(778,0)"/>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(1278,0)">
        <use xlink:href="#MJX-13046891-TEX-N-56"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

Except for some empty tags, I found the question: The property "viewBox" of Svg.
The case of the viewbox attribute in the tag has changed.
the source "viewBox" become "viewbox" in parse.
I try to change name "viewbox" to "viewBox" in browser, and render success.
And now, Just only one question:
How to ensure the capitalization of the original node names when parsing HTML in libxml.
I am a beginner using libxml.
Any help is welcome.

XML is case sensitive, but that doesn't mean that the parser should change capital letters to lower case. For SVG (and HTML), it is actually strange that some attributes are camel case (I know its doesn't answer your question).

libxml2's HTML parser doesn't support HTML5. It's mostly useless these days.
